# Android Studio If Statement Problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Click Event

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
Button button=(Button) v;
((Button) v).setText("clicked");
```

Changes BackGround to an image

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.BackGround);
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mapwork);
```

Makes Certain Items Disapear

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
EditText mText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
mText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Changes what is in the output if they put in a certain number

```
EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
if("8" == mText.getText().toString()){
    mText.setText("That does not work!");
}
}
```

When I test the application the If statement never happens even when the requirements are met. I have tried look for an answer and have not found one. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it will work

```
   if(mText.getText().toString().equals("8")){
mText.setText("That does not work!");}
```